# Azure AppInsight Application map as an raw extract instead of application map

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to get a raw data extract in place of pictorial application map that shows connected dependencies and calls to different connected upstream and downstream application.

Comment: Can you explain a little more of your question? eg. if an applicaton calls an api, then it(the relationship of the two) will be displayed in application map, what data do you wanna fetch?

Comment: we got lot of environments and sometimes it is hard to view the application map every time to find the end point and details. if in a way I can get json extract , I can write some smarts to view it in regular basis. The thing our environment connects with various backends and source. it may change on request. it is time consuming to lookup in Azure . May be some kind of real time report from it can be helpful.